# replacing a value in all columns with value of that column

Tags: matlab, replace

How do I replace all the 1s in ALL columns with the number of that column? I can already do it column by column:

output(output(:,3)==1,3) = 3;
output(output(:,4)==1,4) = 4;
output(output(:,5)==1,5) = 5;
etc...

but I feel like a fool writing that out for every single column. There should be a way to do them all at once right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) for this:

```
[rowIdx,colIdx] = find(output==1);
output(output==1) = colIdx;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you're trying to do, but you could use a MATLAB **for** loop.

```
for i=1:numberOfColumns,
    output(:,i) = i;
end
```

Is this sort of like you're after...?

**Edit:**

```
for x=1:numberOfRows,
    for y=1:numberOfColumns,
        if output(x, y) == 1
            output(x, y) == y
        end
    end
end
```

By the way I may have the columns/rows the wrong way round because I can't remember which way MATLAB represents its matricies!

Comment: That just replaces everything with the column number. I only want to replace the 1s within the columns (and leave everything else the same).

Comment: Thanks, though I can't really get it to work. Jonas' answer does the trick without a loop.

Comment: Kk, without further information I can't help much more I'm afraid! Jonas's solution is a really nice one though! :)