# MySQL and Matlab - Replacing a whole column of data

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

I'm working on a program that takes in some data from a database in MySQL, changes some numbers, and then overwrites the old data on MySQL with the new stuff. (Specifically, the data I'm taking in is output from a weather forecasting model). What I'm struggling with is being able to replace the old data in the database with the edited data.

In my program, the new data (solar radiation values) is a column of numbers in the 3rd column of the matrix WxData (so it can be accessed with WxData(:,3)).

In the MySQL database, the values I want to change are under the column titled "radiation" in the table "wrf". "dbConn" is the name of the database connection.

I tried something like

```
     update(dbConn, 'wrf', {'radiation'}, WxData(:,3), 'WHERE radiation > -1')
```

The update function in the database toolbox in Matlab requires a where clause input so I just put something that is always true. But this method doesn't seem to work...it ends up changing every single radiation value in the database table to the same number (possibly the value at WxData(1,3)).

I've tried a couple other ways but nothing worked. How can I just replace the whole column of radiation values in the database with a new column? Seems like it should be simple.

Comment: see similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460956/replacing-a-value-in-all-columns-with-value-of-that-column

Comment: basically use the find method

Comment: I don't see how this helps me with writing the column to the database - changing it in matlab is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not think in columns or vectors.
Therefore your method simply cannot work, it is not a syntax issue.

If you want to do this, you can assign ID's to the rows in SQL, import these into matlab as well and then put the ID in the where clause and run it for each line.

Comment: I'm new with SQL...can you help me out/link to to a place where I can learn how to do this